# Open AI gym too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuK22.jpg)

I'm trying to run Open ai gym on my jupyter notebook, but I keep getting this error. In the problematic line 17, there are 4 variables that match, why am I getting this error? The development environment is M1 Mac.

Comment: FYI - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

check how many parameter is return by following function.

```
env.step(action)
```

It may be return less than 4 parameters.